# Elegant Handling of Scala Future[Either]]

Tags: scala, either

I have a type whose shape is like this:

```
val myType: Future[Either[MyError, TypeA]] = // some value
```

I know that I could pattern match on this and get to the Right or Left type, but the problem is that I would have to nest my pattern matching logic. I'm looking for much more elegant way of handling this? Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you need monad transformers, which unfortunately the scala core does not provide. The comparable type in scalaz would be `EitherT[Task, MyError, TypeA]`. You can do operations like `map`, `flatMap`, etc over that in a sensible way.

Comment: Nope! using scalaz is not an option for this project!

Comment: You can't add dependencies? I guess you could roll your own `EitherT`?

Comment: I did that in the end! I came up with an EitherFut implementation on my own!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you encode your `MyError` as an exception, you don't need the `Either` anymore and can simply patternMatch against the completion, or use a `recoverWith` to map it to another type:

```
myType.onComplete {
  case Success(t) =>
  case Failure(e) =>
}
```

To map your existing `Either` types you could do something like this:

```
case class MyException(e: MyError) extends Exception

def eitherToException[A](f: Future[Either[MyError,A]]): Future[A] = {
  f.flatMap {
    case Left(e) => Future.failed(MyException(e))
    case Right(x) => Future.successful(x)
  }
}

val myType2 = eitherToException(myType)
```

Alternatively, if `MyError` and `TypeA` are under your control, you could create a common super type and pattern match against that:

```
sealed trait MyResult
final case class MyError() extends MyResult
final case class TypeA() extends MyResult

myType.map {
  case MyError() => ...
  case TypeA() => ...
}
```

Comment: No! having MyResult as a super type does not work and I don't find it a good idea to exploit inheritance for the sake of it! TypeA was just one example., as all my service methods are returning an Either with MyError or  the corresponding case class type which the service method is handling!

Comment: I think the most elegant solution is the one involving myFuture.onComplete and make MyError an exception. It makes sense, it works, it's elegant. Comment aside, @sparkr check your manners pal.

Comment: @Arne: Thanks for the post, but I've been pretty irritated with using meaningless inheritance structure in the name of Cake pattern, where the inheriting class and inherited class has no relation at all! Sorry if I was impolite!

Comment: @sparkr No problem. The sealed trait encoding case classes is a common pattern for Messaging, such as Akka. It does smell like inheritance mis-use compared to OO languages, but is quite accepted as a scala pattern (And i've been doing a lot of Akka lately, so my mind is in a messaging frame)

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom extractor objects:

```
object FullSuccess {
  def unapply[T](x: Try[Either[MyError, T]]) = x match {
    case Success(Right(x)) => Some(x)
    case _ => None
  }
}

object PartSuccess {
  def unapply[T](x: Try[Either[MyError, T]]) = x match {
    case Success(Left(err)) => Some(err)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

And

```
val myType: Future[Either[MyError, TypeA]] = // some value

myType.onComplete {
  case FullSuccess(x) => ... // equivalent to case Success(Right(x))
  case PartSuccess(x) => ... // equivalent to case Success(Left(x))
  case Failure(e) => ...
}
```